# ListView ItemChecked event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, listview

I have a ListView where each item has a checkbox.  Initially there are no events attached and I set the state of the checkboxes programatically.  After this I attach an ItemCheckedEventHandler and the event handler fires for each of the events that occurred before the handler was attached.  Is there a way that I can clear the event queue before attaching the handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to re-create when the event was added in the form constructor/InitializeComponent method.

And I was able to get around the problem by adding the event in the form's load event instead of the constructor/InitializeComponent method.

Answer (score -2):

It's hacky, and I don't like it, but `Application.DoEvents()` might work for you.