# Event is firing before it is initialized?

Tags: c#

At startup I am populating a listview with checkboxes enabled. Later-on I need to handle an *listView.ItemChecked* event. To prevent the event from firing at startup for each listview item I tried to initialize the event in the constructor after the listview is populated, as follows

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            populateListview();

            this.listView1.ItemChecked += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventHandler(this.ListView1_ItemChecked);
        }

        private void populateListview()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string[] s = new string[] { "Value " + i, "sub 1 " + i, "sub 2" + i };
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(s);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately this does not work and the event gets triggered 10 times before the form is opened.
The workaround I found is to initialize the event in a Form_Load event rather than in the constructor. This works, but still I do not understand why the first method does not.
Could somebody explain why is that?

Comment: Did you check if your _ListView1_ItemChecked_ is not already established as your event handler for the ItemChecked event by the form designer? In that case in the InitializeComponent it is alread setup as the event handler.

Comment: It is not there, I removed it

Comment: I suppose that list view items are not created actually when event is initialised in the ctor. But they are created and method is firing when form is opened (controls are appearing on the form)

Comment: I stand to be corrected. I have tried your example and the behavior is as you have described above. I have also found someone here with the same problem and with the same solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799629/listview-itemchecked-event No idea why this happens. It happens only when the property Checkboxes is true

Comment: I think it is related to the order of the creation of the underlying Windows controls and the initial state of the checkboxes. The property IsHandleCreated after the _populatelistview_  is false. So the C# object (ListView) exists in your application and you can use it and set its properties but it is not yet created in Windows. When code reaches the form load instead the control exists also in windows (IsHandleCreated = true) but at that point every checkbox in your listview has raised its ItemChecked because its state changed from indeterminate to unchecked. Needs to be verified though.

Comment: Often is a windows form project events on controls will fire before the control is fully constructed.  The solution is to add a test for the number of rows >= 0.  The row count is initially set to -1.  When the columns are constructed the the row count is set to zero.  The form constructor finalizes after the method in the base class.  You can solve issue either by testing the number of rows or adding a Load event and registering the event in the load method.

Comment: That is fairly ugly, but unavoidable.  Good odds you prefer the ItemCheck event instead, it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Indeed, ItemCheck seems to behave as expected. I'll test it in production, it is definitely cleaner than using one event to initialize another ... Thanks for the tip, Hans